# table inside table td

Tags: html

I have table td inside that am using another table but text and fields are not coming on same line,i have tried with padding,cellso but nothing worked for me

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Label </td>
        <td>
            <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                <tr>
                    <td> <input type=checkbox> Field Name </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @prakashkadakol: Its hard enough to debug HTML alignment/layout problems by looking at the markup, so please :) some HTML code will be helpful

Comment: <table><tr><td>Label</td><td><table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr><td><input type=checkbox>Field Name</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>

Comment: Here Label Goone to top and Field Name slightly gone to bottom even tried with valign attributes

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2ZX7v/ try this. But please, accept some of your 10 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is just fine. 
What do you think is wrong with it?
I tested it out and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Label</td>
<td>
  <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type=checkbox />Field Name
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

open this in the browser, and tell me what's wrong with it?